# How to open a file outside working directory in c++ using <iostream> library?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my own cmd in Windows. I need an alternative to the fstream library which I'm not familiar with. I have heard about the iostream ibrary for file input/output also if there is such a thing can you show me an example? I'm also getting an error with this code in Code::Blocks:

> 60: No function matching for call to std::basic_ifstream< char >::open(std::__cx::string&)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

void processor_xH(std::string);
void motherboard_xH(std::string);
void prccept(std::string);
void o_app(std::string);
//Contains global variables and functions
std::string command;

int main()
{
//Check whether the system("") command is availible or exit...
if(system(NULL)) std::cout << "Ok..." << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Sorry, an error occured..." << std::endl;
//Now set the color settings and output directory
system("CLS"); system("COLOR 50");
std::cout << "@jedaiCoder $go-do- ";
//Take command as input string
std::getline(std::cin, command);
processor_xH(command);
//Check for specific commands in string
getchar(); return 0;
}

void processor_xH(std::string input)
{
std::string srchI[]={"prccept", "o-app"};
for(int x=0; x<=1; x++)
{
    if((input.find(srchI[x]))!=std::string::npos)
    {
        //Then find the command
        motherboard_xH(srchI[x]);
    }
}
}

void motherboard_xH(std::string x)
{
   if(x=="prccept") prccept(x);//Command for printing file or text
   if(x=="o-app") o_app(x); //Open file for reading writing
}

void prccept(std::string x)
{

}

void o_app(std::string x)//Guys the error is over here
{
std::string y=x.substr(7, 8);
x=x.substr(9, 12);
if(y=="-w" || y=="-r")
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(x);
}
}
```

This project also might contain some other errors so please do point them out.

Also please excuse my using of the system("") command as I am a beginner and I know `SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5|BACKGROUND RED)` but I want to set background color for the whole program.

Comment: please give your salary to the good guy that fix your code for you.

Comment: "Please read my code and fix it" - that, *right there* is the reason for my down vote.

Comment: Interesting, the program continues even though an error occurred.  IMO, not a good thing.

Comment: If variables don't change their values, declare them as `const`, such as `const std::string srchI[] = "prccept", "o-app"};`

Comment: Thanks @Jesper Juhl, I don't often ask questions and I didn't know not to include the Please read my code and fix it. I'll be more carefull next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using an older compiler that doesn't like `open(std::string&)`.

Try this instead:

```
file.open(x.c_str());
```

Also consider passing strings by reference.  If you are not changing the string, pass by constant reference.  If you like using a copy of the parameter's value, then use a different variable in your function and assign it a copy of the parameter.

BTW, the idiom for a `for` loop is:

```
for (index = 0; index < quantity; ++index)
```

So if there are two strings, the statement becomes:

```
for(int x=0; x < 2; x++)
```